compute Local volatility by Quantlib
I have a dataset of shape (11,18) corresponding to implied volatility, with which I need to calculate the Dupire local volatility. However, I'm encountering a problem with ql.BlackVarianceSurface which results in a RuntimeError: mismatch between date vector and vol matrix columns.
maturities = data['K,T']
strikes = data.columns[1:].astype(float)
vol_data = data.iloc[:, 1:] / 100

# Set the fixed parameters
S0 = 4975.5  # Spot price
r = 0.03568686  # Risk-free rate
q = 0.0  # Dividend yield

# Set today's date in QuantLib
today = ql.Date.todaysDate()

# Setting up the calendar and day counter
calendar = ql.NullCalendar()
dayCounter = ql.Actual365Fixed()

# Convert maturity strings to QuantLib periods
def convert_maturity(period_str):
    units = period_str[-1]
    if units == 'M':
        return ql.Period(int(period_str[:-1]), ql.Months)
    elif units == 'Y':
        return ql.Period(int(period_str[:-1]), ql.Years)

maturity_dates = [today + convert_maturity(m) for m in maturities]

# Ensure lengths match
assert len(maturity_dates) == vol_data.shape[0], "Maturity dates and volatility rows do not match"
assert len(strikes) == vol_data.shape[1], "Strike prices and volatility columns do not match"

# Create the volatility surface
vol_surface = ql.BlackVarianceSurface(
    today, calendar, maturity_dates, strikes.tolist(), vol_data.values.tolist(), dayCounter
)

# Create yield and dividend term structures
rates_ts = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(ql.FlatForward(today, r, dayCounter))
dividend_ts = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(ql.FlatForward(today, q, dayCounter))

# Create local volatility surface
local_vol_surface = ql.LocalVolSurface(ql.BlackVolTermStructureHandle(vol_surface), rates_ts, dividend_ts, ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(S0)))

# Example usage: Evaluate the local volatility at a specific strike and time
strike_example = 5000
time_example = 0.5  # in years
local_vol = local_vol_surface.localVol(time_example, strike_example, True)

I think that for QuantLib, the matrix must be of shape (n,n). I am completely stuck and cannot find another solution to proceed. Do you have any suggestions?
